# Can you run two infinite loops, one with an input, at the same time in python?

Tags: python, loops, infinite

I've seen some posts about running infinite loops in python but nothing covering this specific topic.

I was wondering if you could run code that asked the user a question for an input, whilst another infinite loop was running in the background?
Sorry if this is stupid, I'm new to python.

```
import time

num = 1
while True:
    num = num + 1
    time.sleep(0.1)

while True:
    ques = input("What is your favourite type of burger? ")
    if ques == "quit":
        break;

print(num)
# here i am wondering whether i can keep the first loop going while the second loop asks me questions
```

Comment: You're looking for either [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) or [asynchronous programming](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using threads.

```
import time
from threading import Thread

num = 1


def numbers():
    global num
    while True:
        num = num + 1
        print(num)
        time.sleep(0.1)


def question():
    while True:
        ques = input("What is your favourite type of burger? ")
        if ques == "quit":
            break


threads = [
    Thread(target=numbers),
    Thread(target=question)
]

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

That said this code doesn't do anything meaningful.

Comment: There's nothing to be gained by declaring *num* globally. Why run *question()* in a thread? The *join()* loop will never end because *numbers()* runs indefinitely. And this is the accepted answer.

Comment: I think the point of question was to get a conceptual answer on how to run two infinite loops in parallel rather than actually implementing an infinite counter that runs in the background.